# How to tell if an object is an instance of a class

Tags: class, dart, dart-mirrors

How can I determine whether an object is of a class or not in the Dart language?

I'm looking to do something like the following:

```
if (someObject.class.toString() == "Num") {
    ...
}
```

And what is the returned value type?  Will it have to be a String?

---

The mirror library has been up and down and seems to be subject to rapid change right now, as the one thing I did find simply did not work as shown.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

- By using the `is` and `is!` operators, like this:

  ```dart
  if (someObject is T)
  ```

  From the [documentation](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#type-test-operators):

  > The `is` and `is!` operators are handy for checking types. The result of
  >   `obj is T` is true if `obj` implements the interface specified by `T`. For
  >   example, `obj is Object` is always true.
- Using the [Mirrors API](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/continuous/dart_mirrors.html) (see [this example](http://blog.dartwatch.com/2012/06/dartmirrors-reflection-api-is-on-way.html)):

  ```dart
  Expect.equals('T', someObject.simpleName)
  ```

Comment: Thanks!   Works beautifully.  See quick test below:                                                                                                                         ....                                                              bool noteIsString(var note) { 
  
    return( note is String );
  
  }

  bool test0 = noteIsString("string");
  
  bool test1 = noteIsString(123.45);
  
  print("test0 result is: $test0");   //=> true
  
  print("test1 result is: $test1");   //=> false

Answer (score 57):

Recently `Object` got the `runtimeType` getter. So now, we may not only compare type of object with another type, but actually get the *class name* of an object.

As in:

```dart
myObject.runtimeType.toString()
```

Furthermore, in the current version of Dart, you can skip the `toString` operation and directly compare `runtimeType` of object with target type:

```dart
myObject.runtimeType == int
```

or

```dart
myObject.runtimeType == Animal
```

Comment: One can compare directly using for instance `myObject.runtimeType == int`.

Comment: Any advantages compared to `myObject is int`? `is` also returns true even when it only implements the other type this might not be the desired results in some cases. It was mentioned occasionally that `runtimeType` is not reliable because it can be overridden and should only be used for debugging purposes.

Comment: I believe equality with runtimeType give you more dynamic capabilities. For example see that function: `testType(object,type) => object.runtimeType == type`. You can use it as `testType(myObject,int)` I believe it is impossible with `is` operator. But I should check it, maybe I wrong

Comment: I've checked, my guess was right. You cannot pass `type literal` as parameter of function and then use it in `is` operation. So `isOfType(obj, Type type) => obj is type` is incorrect but `isOfType(obj, Type type) => obj.runtimeType == type` works well

Comment: Better answer yet

Comment: If you use dart for web, minified to js code will return minified value!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple explanation with a solution.

You have:

`Object obj =t1`; 
where `t1` is an object of class T.

And you have other object T called `t`.

`T t = new T()`;

How to check if `obj` is the same type of `t` ?

Solution:

```
if(obj is t)
     print('obj is typeof t')
   else print('obj is not typeof t')
```