# Print detailed structure / type information of a variable's value

Tags: dart

I wonder, if a dart or flutter method exists, which returns complete type information about the structure of a variable's value as a string.

E.g., if some `print( someValue.toString() );` emits this

```
  {"user":"userName","state":"valid"}
```

I don't know if it is a Map or a String.

**But how do I get a string, which describes a variable's value / structure?**

Something, that's like PHP's `print_r()`, which print stuff like this:

```
Array
(
    [a] => Apfel
    [b] => Banane
    [c] => Array
        (
            [0] => x
            [1] => y
            [2] => z
        )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing *like **`print_r()`** available natively in Dart*.
However, it would be possible to use the following functionalities to build e.g. a function like `print_r()` from PHP.

You can evaluate the type of `someValue` using `runtimeType`.

```
String someValueType = someValue.runtimeType.toString();
String someValueString = someValue.toString();
```

If you want to compare, you can also use `is`. More on [that here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12879961/6509751).
Dart is a strongly typed language, which means that you could also enforce types (`List a; String b`), which makes a function like `print_r()` redundant for Dart.

Comment: I'm aware of these aspects. Add a line to text, that states that no print_r() like method exists. And I'm going to accept your insert.

Comment: @SteAp I added that. I think that Dart does not need anything like `print_r()` because of its typing.

Answer (score 1):

If it is about server-side code you can use reflection to create a function that produces such an output for every value.

If it is about your own classes, you can implement `toString()` to make the objects render themselves this way when they are printed

```
class Person {
  Foo(this.firstName, this.lastName);

  String firstName;
  String lastName;

  @override
  String toString() => '''
firstName: $firstName
lastName: $lastName
''';      
}

print(new Person('John', 'Doe'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do is

```
print(”$someValue“);
```

It will return a structured string which similar to JSON.